# Getting cart content inside *.tpl file

Tags: php, prestashop, smarty, prestashop-1.6

For first: I am a complete Smarty newbie.

I've created custom PrestaShop `*.tpl` file which is used by custom CMS page and now I need to get an IDs of products which are already added to shopping cart. Is there any possibility to achieve this?

My first thought was to use `$cart` variable and make a foreach loop, but then I've realized... that variable doesn't store cart items.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You were not that far, just try :

```
{$products = $cart->getProducts()}
```

Then you will be able to make some loop :).

Answer (score 0):

like this:

```
{foreach from=$cart->getProducts() item=product}
    {$product.name}
{/foreach}
```